# Using dynamic preloaded image in Flutter/Dart

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I currently have images which the image name is returned by a function and is dynamically called based on a variable like this:

```
String _setImage() {
  if (currentQuestion > 1 && currentQuestion < 11) {
    return "assets/images/image_$intensityIndex.png";
  } else {
    return "assets/images/image.png";
  }
}
```

I want to switch to preloading the images and I am using the technique described at [Preload images in a stateful widget on Flutter](https://alex.domenici.net/archive/preload-images-in-a-stateful-widget-on-flutter), but I am not sure how to have the function return an image which the name is dynamically determined based on another variable. Here is what I have so far:

```
void initState() {
   super.initState();

  image0 = Image.asset('assets/images/image_0.png'); 
  image1 = Image.asset('assets/images/image_1.png');
  image2 = Image.asset('assets/images/image_2.png');
  image3 = Image.asset('assets/images/image_3.png');
}

void didChangeDependencies() {
  super.didChangeDependencies();

  precacheImage(image0.image, context);
  precacheImage(image1.image, context);
  precacheImage(image2.image, context);
  precacheImage(image3.image, context);
}

Image _setImage() {
  if (currentQuestion > 1 && currentQuestion < 11) {
    return ______________;
  } else {
    return image0;
  }
}
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Cache it before adding to `Image.asset()` by keeping asset path in a variable.

Comment: Thanks @Blasanka!  It is working how I expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am not sure how to return an image which the name is dynamically
>   determined based on another variable

You don't need to `return` with precach because if you use exact image that you cache.

Ex:

```
precacheImage('assets/images/image_1.png'); // if this is the image name

Image.asset('assets/images/image_1.png'); // when you use this it is getting from the cache but the path should be same.
```

If I explain it another way:

```
precacheImage("assets/images/image_$intensityIndex.png"); // image_1.png
Image.asset('assets/images/image_1.png'); // when you do this, asset taking from the cache by looking at the path.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @blasanka.  The “return” isn’t for the precache. It’s because it’s inside a function.  I’ve updated my question with more code.

Comment: For clarification, I still need to keep the image0 = Image.asset('assets/images/image_0.png'); in the initState() and the precacheImage in didChangeDependencies(), right?

Comment: @Stephanie Since, `initState` invoke before `didChangeDependencies`, what you are doing is useless for the first visit(What you are doing is caching after assign to a widget). Try `precacheImage` in `initState` and in `didChangeDependencies` assign to the `Image.asset`.